# Stop program execution and return if else condition is hit

Tags: ios, swift

In the sign-up process for my app, I have two function - first checks the user's entered handle to see if it's already taken, and then the second function sets the rest of their values:

```
@IBAction func setupDoneButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    checkHandle()
    setUserInfo()
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "setupToChat", sender: nil)
}
```

The `checkHandle` function seems to be doing it's job, in that it checks the database then prints the "else" condition print statement - however I don't see the alert, and the program simply segues into the app.

If that handle is already in use, I need to program to halt and not move on to `setUserInfo` and then segue into the app. I'd like to display the alert that I have in there, then allow the user to try again with a different handle.

This is the `checkHandle` function:

```
func checkHandle() {

    if self.handleTextField.text != nil {
        if let handle = self.handleTextField.text {

            let handleRef: FIRDatabaseReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users")
            handleRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "handle").queryEqual(toValue: "\(handle)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

                if (snapshot.value is NSNull) {
                    print("handle not in use") // handle not found
                    userRef.child("handle").setValue(handle)
                } else {
                    print("Handle already in use. Value: \(snapshot.value)") // handle is in use
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Handle Taken", message: "Please choose a different handle", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.actionSheet)

                    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {(alert :UIAlertAction!) in
                    })
                    alertController.addAction(okAction)

                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }

            })
        }
    }
}
```

What can I do to ensure that the sign-up process stops in the case of an already-existing handle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve it like that:

First make `checkHandle()` a function that takes completion like `checkHandle(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void)`

Then inside this function invoke `completion(true)` if the `if` condition is met and `completion(false)` if it is not. Then in your button handler use `checkHandle()` like that:

```
checkHandle { [weak self] success in 
     guard success else { return }

     self?.setUserInfo()
     self?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "setupToChat", sender: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is just continuing processing and not taking any conditational action. I would suggest that you make your checkHandle function return a boolean value and then respond accordingly.

```
func checkHandle(handle: String) -> Bool {
    someBool = // some logic to see if handle exists.
    return someBool 
}

@IBAction func setupDoneButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    if checkHandle() {
        setUserInfo()
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "setupToChat", sender: nil)
    } else {
       // present an error, or make suggestions etc
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func setupDoneButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    if checkHandle()
    {
       setUserInfo()
       self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "setupToChat", sender: nil)
    }   
}

func checkHandle() -> Bool {
    let isAvailable = false
    if self.handleTextField.text != nil {
        if let handle = self.handleTextField.text {

            let handleRef: FIRDatabaseReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users")
            handleRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "handle").queryEqual(toValue: "\(handle)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

                if (snapshot.value is NSNull) {
                    print("handle not in use") // handle not found
                    userRef.child("handle").setValue(handle)
                    isAvailable = true
                } else {
                    print("Handle already in use. Value: \(snapshot.value)") // handle is in use
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Handle Taken", message: "Please choose a different handle", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.actionSheet)

                    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {(alert :UIAlertAction!) in
                    })
                    alertController.addAction(okAction)

                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    isAvailable = false
                }

            })
        }
    }
   if isAvailable
   {
      return true
   }
   return false
}
```

Comment: "Unexpected non-void return value in void function" error on both the returns

Comment: I believe you also need to add return statement at the bottom, otherwise it won't compile :)

Comment: As for @KingTim make sure you add `-> Bool` in your function definition

Comment: I did, the function is `func checkHandle() -> Bool {`

Comment: Could the `if self.handleTextField.text != nil` and `if let handle = self.handleTextField.text` conditionals be wanting returns also?

Comment: Try adding `return false` as the last line of the function

Comment: `return false` on the last line didn't seem to make a difference

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142618/discussion-between-mr-hedgehog-and-kingtim).